# Why is dot product also projection times magnitude?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, change-of-basis

Can someone explain why is dot product is defined as projection * magnitude. Instead only projection. Also, why is a projection to the axis to the change of basis written: $$\dfrac{\vec{b}*\vec{v}}{||v||^2}$$ Instead of $$\dfrac{\vec{b}*\vec{v}}{||v||}$$ I know that it doesn't work, but why not isn't that scalar projection. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my reasoning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the orthogonal projection of $\vec b$ in direction $\vec v\neq\vec 0$ is the scalar product of $\vec b$ and the unit vector in direction $\vec v$ times that unit vector: $$\left(\vec b*\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}\right)\cdot \frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}=
\frac{\vec b*\vec v}{\|\vec v\|^2}\cdot\vec v.$$

Comment: Projections are typically defined via dot products, not the other way around. Projections are normalized because you don't want to accidentally end up scaling your vector. Consider $b = (1,0)$ projected onto $(2,0)$.. You would end up with $(2,0)$ if you don't rescale your vector so you've actually stretched $b$, thus fundamentally changing it, not just grabbing the part in the direction of $v$.

Comment: The magnitude of a vector isn't a natural part of the projection calculation, rather it's the dot product of the vector with itself. I would write this as $\frac{b * v}{v * v}$ to make it more obvious that the magnitude is irrelevant.